# Wrong calculations of areas of combined polygons containing objects from another table in MapInfo Pro

Tags: gis, area, mapinfo

I am stuck with a problem in MapInfo Pro.

I have three tables with polygons and have combined polygons from table 1 and 2 into larger polygons. Now I am only interested in the area of the ones that contain polygons from table three.

For some reason I keep getting wrong results when I make queries on that selection - it seems as though if there is 4 table 3 polygons inside the combined polygons I also get the area of the combined polygon 4 times!

When I make queries on the combined polygons I get nice results on area, number of polygons etc.. It is only when I make a selection of combined areas containing table 3 objects it goes wrong (`Where condition= combined polygons.obj Contain table3.obj`). For some reason the results get duplicated several times.

Comment: Use Group By, on an ID column for example, to return unique records from your combined table.

Comment: I added an ID column and used Group by ID and it worked :-) Thank you for your help.

Comment: Formatting, removed unnecessary words